# How to send a CloudWatchEvent from a lambda to an EventBridge destination

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a lambda which is triggered by an **EventBridge** custom bus. I want to send another event to the customer bus at the end of the function processing. I created a **destination** in the lambda to send to the same custom bus.

I have the following code where the function handler will return a **CloudWatchEvent**. This is not working.

```
public async Task<CloudWatchEvent<object>> FunctionHandler(CloudWatchEvent<object> evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
    return await ProcessMessageAsync(evnt, context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My lambda was being triggered by S3 input event (which is asynchronous), I tried adding destination on Lambda "success" to EventBridge bus, created a rule to capture that and send it to CloudWatch logs but it didn't seem to work.

Turns out, while creating the Rule in EventBridge, event pattern was set to:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.lambda"]
}
```

Which is what you get if you are using the console and selecting AWS Lambda as the AWS Service. [image: Event Source]

Infuriated, I couldn't seem to get it to work even with a simple event. On further inspection, I looked at the input event and realized that it wants `lambda` and not `aws.lambda`. It is also mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

So to fix it, I changed it to

```
{
  "source": ["lambda"]
}
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given a shot to [AWS Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/). There are 4 types of Destinations supported

1. SQS Queue
2. SNS Topic
3. Event Bridge Event Bus
4. Lambda Function itself.

Comment: I'm using EventBridge Event Bus. I also set up the destination in AWS Console. I also have the code which I posted in the original question. But the event is not going to the EventBus or the Lamda it is targeting. There is no C# example that shows what type need to be returned form the **FunctionHandler**. Is it **CloudWatchEvent** or **PutEventRequest**. None of them worked for me.

Comment: It works for me only when I send the event to the EventBridge event bus using **AWSEventBridgeClient.PutEents**. With the destination set up, just returning the event from the **FunctionHandler** should work.

Comment: this works fine, not sure if you configured it by adding necessary permissions. Lambda Destination works only for lambdas which are called asynchronously.

Comment: How do I call Lambda Destination from a lambda asynchronously?

Comment: Please take a look at the post I've attached you can choose from 4 options while configuring the destination.

Comment: I have already configured the destination as **Event Bridge Event Bus**. How to call the Lambda which is trigged from the events from that **Event Bus** is my question.

Comment: something like this 
aws  lambda invoke-async --function-name myfunction--invoke-args args.json

Comment: I am pretty much sure there must be the API call for the relevant one in the SDK. This is the API call https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_InvokeAsync.html